# How do I allow anonymous access to my mvc3 app using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, windows-authentication, anonymous-access

I have an MVC3 **Intranet app** that uses Windows authentication. I'm now using a third party service that will make notification calls to my app. I've already created a listener for these API calls but not sure how I can allow anonymous access to that single view in my app.

My IIS7 settings are as follows:

```
Anonymous - Enabled <---------- Use Domain User
ASP.NET Impersonation - Disabled
Basic Authentication - Disabled
Digest Authentication - Disabled
Forms Authentication - Disabled
Windows Authentication - Enabled - HTTP 401 Challange
```

Additionally, in my web.config file, authentication mode is set to Windows.

With that said, is there a way to allow anonymous access to a single view in my MVC app?

Comment: did you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @BongoSharp this question is too old!!! i think bellow answer has worked as best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where path is your end url, add this your web.config.

```
<location path="MyController/MyAction">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Or decorate the action with AllowAnonymousAttibute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute(v=vs.108).aspx.